# Nifi fetchs3object fails with 404 NoSuchKey the specified key does not exist after using lists3 to obtain key. key includes "=" and "/"

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have about 3 million objects with an athena compatible schema using prefixes for partitions like:

matchplayers/server=stadia/mapname=BestMap/gamemode=duo/stadia::account.345::6858e678-c785-4c4c-97e9-9f7791ef356c.json.gz

I use lists3 on nifi to obtain the objects, and then pass them to FetchS3 on nifi, but i get 404 no such key error from S3.

I think it has something to do with the "=" character in the text file and i tried using ${filename:urlEnconde()} as the objectkey parameter but urlEnconde() didn't change anything on the key.

What else could i use?

EDIT: Actual error message on nifi:
[FetchS3Object error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJm3C.png)

Comment: Try to update the post with the actual error message from NiFi.  It should be clear what the specific issue is.   You may need to escape the characters in the filename, but it isn't clear in your post if you are having an issue with Key or Filename.   In my experience S3 keys work without any character formatting and filenames will need to be escaped.

Comment: I posted a link to the error I'm seeing. It is not clear to me why it is telling me the specified key does not exist, when i obtained the key directly from ListS3 processor and the file is definitely in the bucket.

Comment: Can you show the input flow file's content/attributes going to Fetchs3 and the configuration of FetchS3 ?